# select element starting with class name and contain part of string

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm gonna select element with class but named 'path_from' etc.

Let me show you example

```
<div class='path_from_5_to_6'></div>
<div class='_6'></div>
<div class='path_from_6_to_5'></div>
<div class='path_from_3_to_2'></div>
```

I want to select element which class is start with path_from but contain '_6'

How can I do this?

Comment: [`class='(path_from[^']*6.*?)'`](https://regex101.com/r/tA5iD7/1)

Comment: Note that unless you're going for a quick-and-dirty one-time script, you should really avoid using regular expressions to parse HTML. See [this glorious answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1678362) if you're not convinced

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `[class^="path_from"][class*="_6"]` attribute selector

- `[class^="path_from"]` - class starts with `path_from`
- `[class*="_6"]` - class contains `_6`

```css
[class^="path_from"][class*="_6"] {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='path_from_5_to_6'>DIV</div>
<div class='_6'>DIV</div>
<div class='path_from_6_to_5'>DIV</div>
<div class='path_from_3_to_2'>DIV</div>
```

Comment: I did not saw your answer. I upvote you and delete mine because it was the same as mine \o/

Answer (score 0):

here is an example

```css
[class*="path"][class*="6"] {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="path_To_6"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't. That is what you use `class` and `id` for. `class` for related elements and `id` for individual elements.

```
<div class="path_6" id="path_from_5_to_6"></div>
<div id="_6"></div>
<div class="path_6" id="path_from_6_to_5"></div>
<div id="path_from_3_to_2"></div>
```

Then you select using `.path_6` only:

```
.path_6 {
  // styles
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can do it with type selectors. Look at @NenadVracar answer.